# Exception : Transaction Scope nested incorrectly

Tags: .net, exception

I have created an console email application reading application from outlook. Whenever an a new message arrive in the inbox call an asynchronous method. This async method call a webservice by sending a web request and executes the function inside the service.These application is run like a scheduler job.These process is working when first email come to the inbox. At second it got exception **Exception : Transaction Scope nested incorrectly** .When i try to close the email application and then start, at that time it's work fine. How can i resolve this exception?
 **Below are the code for Call  Service from Email Application**

```
static void Save(string userAlias, string engagementName, string documentTranferId, string fileName, string fileSize,string activityName)
        {
            try
            {
                userAlias = userAlias.ToLower();
                var url = new StringBuilder();
                url.Append(
               string.Format("https://myapp.com:8443/Services/MyService/Test.svc/Save?User={0}&Engagement={1}&FileName={2}&DocumentTrasferID={3}&fileSize={4}&ActivityName={5}",userAlias, engagementName, fileName, documentTranferId, fileSize, activityName));
                Console.WriteLine(url);
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url.ToString());
                CurrentUrl = url.ToString();
                var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("testr", "123Test", "jemi");
                request.Credentials = networkCredential;
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
                var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string responseResult = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
                responseStream.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(responseResult);
            }
            catch(Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ee.Message);
            }

        }
```

**Service Details-
Endpoint**

```
 <OperationContract()> _
  <WebGet(UriTemplate:="/Save?User={User}&Engagement={Engagement}&FileName={FileName}&DocumentTrasferID={documentTrasferID}&fileSize={fileSize}&ActivityName={ActivityName}", RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
    Function Save(ByVal User As String, ByVal Engagement As String, ByVal FileName As String, ByVal DocumentTrasferID As String, ByVal fileSize As String, ByVal ActivityName As String) As String
```

**Implementation**

```
Public Function Save(ByVal User As String, ByVal Engagement As String, ByVal FileName As String, ByVal DocumentTrasferID As String, ByVal fileSize As String, ByVal ActivityName As String) As String Implements IMyInterface.Save
        Dim facade= New MyFacade
        Dim Result As String = facade.Save(User, Engagement, FileName, DocumentTrasferID, fileSize, ActivityName)
        Return Result
    End Function
```

**Facade Class. Here is I got Exception**

```
Public Function Save(Doc doc,string id,string param) As String
Dim facade= New MyFacade
facade.Save(doc, id, param)
End Function
```

Comment: Did you check if the transaction scopes you're using might be incorrectly nested or not disposed?; I don't think there is enough information here to answer this. The problem could be anything. Can you post a repro?

Comment: I am not using any transaction scope

Comment: please post as much information as you can. Right now, the cause of the exception cannot be determined.

Comment: What information you need?

Comment: the full exception as well as some relevant code would be very useful.

Comment: I have an email client and service layer

Comment: only got Transaction Scope nested incorrectly in exception

Comment: I'll make one final try: Can you post the stack trace and relevant code?

Comment: I have update my question by adding the source code

Comment: I find the problem. I have refered a dll to call facade.Save method.Once this method is called transaction scope will be disposed that's why next transaction got exception comes. I can't modify the refered dll to fix the problem.Can i fix these issues from Email Project or service project?

Comment: I have used Email Client for reading mail and calling service and Service project called by Email Client,these project are refred some dll. In that dll i got exception. I need to fix these issue from Email Client and Service Project itself.